# Possible solutions to the crown problem of Archimedes

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, pressure, weight

My teacher was talking about the crown problem, possibly solved by Archimedes using skills about density, weight and other properties that he studied. In the original publication, by Vitruvius in a book about architecture, it says that Archimedes had a enlightenment while taking a bath, where he recognized that his body moved the volume of water equivalente to the volume submerged. Then, he could measure the volume moved when submergin the crown, and then find if it was pure gold, or had silver mixed (a cheaper material that could've been mixed in the making of the crown).

The problem is that some people say it would be difficult to make precise measurements of the water moved when submerging the crown, at that epoque. My teacher, then, said that he read an article once, that talked about 3 possible solutions to the problem. He said that we should find this article and bring it to the next class. I tried to find it but I couldn't (looked over 10 pages of google without success, for a lot of tags).

Does anybody know about na article similar to this one, or know what is the article? Or even better, does someone know these 3 possible solutions?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Without doing your assignment for you, I'm going to introduce you to two excellent resources far better than raw Google: [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com), and the **references** section at the end of every Wikipedia article (to be used in conjunction with the inline citations in the article).

Comment: If I remember correctly he did not measure the changing in the water level. The tale was that Archimedes felt his body being pushed up by the water when bathing... The measurement is based on the Archimedes's floating force (and not on the moving up of the water), which would be very precise, I believe. You should review the tale first.

Comment: have a look at this http://www.math.nyu.edu/~crorres/Archimedes/Crown/CrownIntro.html

Comment: Related story on www.longlongtimeago.com: [‘Eureka!’ – The Story of Archimedes and the Golden Crown](https://www.longlongtimeago.com/once-upon-a-time/great-discoveries/eureka-the-story-of-archimedes-and-the-golden-crown/) mentions another method by using a balance. This seems to be much more accurate than measuring the amount of water displaced on complete immersion.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know with 100% certainty, but according to physical laws, these methods should work:

1- Silver and gold have different melting points. They didn't know about precise melting points for these metals in Archimedes time, but that doesn't really matter. Take a small piece of gold and a small piece of the object to be tested for gold purity. Place them in different crucibles and SLOWLY start increasing the heat. If the object is pure gold, it should melt 100% when the piece of pure gold melts. If it melts at more or less heat than the pure gold piece then it definitely contains impurities.

2- Gold and silver have different densities but you can utilise the density idea other than water displacement method too. Simply take a piece of pure gold and the object to be tested. Now take a large glass jar of at least 3 feet depth. Fill 90% with clean, clear water. Now slowly release both of them (pure gold piece and the crown) in the water. If both of them sink at the same speed (remember, you have dipped them in a jar made of GLASS), then crown is made of pure gold. If it sinks at a different rate, it definitely contains impurities.

I can tell you of a 3rd method too, but I am not going to spoonfeed you totally. Just concentrate at the physical properties of silver and gold and how you can use them. You will find more than half a dozen methods very soon.

Comment: Your first method is good, but I forgot to mention that the tale at the book says that Archimeded couldn't break a piece out of the crown

Comment: Your second method is REALLY good

Comment: At the time no one anywhere in the world knew how to manufacture clear glass and even the less cloudy variants were not available in large batches. Indeed *any* quantity of glass was a luxury item.

Comment: I think: the first should not work because the king would be angry if you damage his crown; the second should not work precisely enough since the falling speeds depend subtly on the experiment conditions (diameter of the glass, length of the glass, not to mention the precise shape of the crown).

Answer (score 0):

If you are not allowed to take a piece of the crown for melting, here is another method which should help. This method incorporates the difference in thermal conductivity of gold and silver, in simple words it means how gold and silver differ in their ability to conduct heat.

Take a rod of pure gold. This rod should be of equal length as the length of the crown. Now take two small pieces of wax. Place one wax piece at the edge of the crown and the other wax piece at the edge of the pure gold bar. Now light up a candle and place the OTHER (the ends far from wax pieces) of gold rod and the crown together on the flame, so that they both get an equal share of heat. Now just notice when the wax pieces start melting. If both wax pieces start melting at the same time, then the crown is pure gold. If crown wax melts at a different time than the gold rod wax, then the crown contains impurities.

For your general knowledge, if the crown contains silver impurity, then its wax piece should start melting before the pure gold rod wax piece because silver has a much better heat conductivity than gold.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Nobody is measuring any temperature anywhere.

I stated "Now just notice WHEN the wax pieces start melting". If the crown is made of pure gold, both wax pieces will start melting at the same time. If it contains impurities, the crown wax piece will start melting at a different time than the pure rod wax piece.

Where did you find the idea of temperature in all of the process?

Comment: Ah. I withdraw that objection, but have another. The thermal conductivity of the crown depends on the cross-section which (in the original story) is highly variable because the object is ornate and spiky---that was the thing that was giving Archimedes trouble in the first place. The physical insight here is fine and I wouldn't down vote on this kind of basis but the answer so far have ignored the context of the legend.

Comment: When talking about thermal conductivity, it is not the shape or the surface area of the object which matters, but its volume. Starting with the good assumption that the crown is made of pure gold, simply weigh the crown and get a rod of equal weight and length as the crown weight and length. This should be a simple enough task.

Comment: The thermal conductivity (measured in W/(m K)) is is a function of the material, put the thermal power (measured in W) is a function of both the temperature difference (which you presumably control) and the cross-section over the length (A/L). The time it takes the wax to melt depends on the shape of the piece connecting the two sides.

Comment: :S Do you mean that a 20 m² sheet of gold with 5 cm thickness will conduct heat at the same speed as a 20 m² sheet of gold with 10 cm thickness?

Comment: No, cross-section divided by length.